# How can I get "id" dynamically to set an object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Well, inside `getOne()` I'm forcing an **id** I used for testing. I need, dynamically, to inform which **id** in`GuiaRecolhimento` I will set in `PagamentoGuia`. How could I do it?

```
@PostMapping
public PagamentoGuia create(@RequestBody  PagamentoGuia pagamentoGuia) {

     GuiaRecolhimento g = repositoryGuia.getOne((long) 764);

     pagamentoGuia.setGuia(g);

     return repository.save(pagamentoGuia);
}
```

Comment: create a dto which consists of id and PagamentoGuia and take it as request body.

Answer (score 0):

Receive the id in the PostMapping url whith a PathVariable.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}")
public PagamentoGuia create(@RequestBody  PagamentoGuia pagamentoGuia, @PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {

    GuiaRecolhimento g = repositoryGuia.getOne(id);

    pagamentoGuia.setGuia(g);

    return repository.save(pagamentoGuia);
}
```

Edit: 
I agree with [Matheus Cirillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9860374/matheus-cirillo)

For you follow the correct semantic according to REST patterns you can use a DTO object.

```
public class PagamentoGuiaDto {
   private Long guiaRecolhimentoId;

   // all attributes of PagamentoGuiaDto
   // all getters and setters
}

@PostMapping
public PagamentoGuia create(@RequestBody  PagamentoGuiaDto dto) {

GuiaRecolhimento g = repositoryGuia.getOne(dto.getPagamentoGuiaId());

PagamentoGuia pagamentoGuia = new PagamentoGuia();
pagamentoGuia.setGuia(g);

// set the values of dto to pagamentoGuia

return repository.save(pagamentoGuia);
```

}

Comment: I already tried that way. It's `"Method Not Allowed"` and error mesasge: `"Request method 'POST' not supported"`.

Comment: Verify if you'are calling the correct method in your frontend application.

Answer (score 0):

**IMHO** you'll have to create a DTO which receives the `GuiaRecolhimento`'s id.

Since you're creating a `PagamentoGuia` in your database, receiving the `id` of `GuiaRecolhimento` as Path Variable is **not** appropriated, since it's not related to the main collection we are referring to (PagamentoGuia).

Use DTO's. That way you follow the correct semantic according to REST patterns.